# listadapter getview function

Tags: android, listview

the problem is happend when I add setContentView in my ListActivity.
here is my oncreate function:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    

    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("item " + i);
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

and here is my adapter getview function :

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

when i running the code I can see message in logcat :
[image]

it's i expected .but the problem comes when add SetContent(View) code in oncreate() function .the logcat message follow this:
[image]

the problem cause picture shows in error postion first   when i want download img from web in thread and bind it on listItem . the first item will show all picture quickly then change as the first item's picture and ohter item show thier picture.
but when i remove the setcontentview code from oncreate the problem is gone.. need help

Comment: your class extends `ListActivity` ? ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. can you post the full code along with layout xml.

Comment: i know listActivity have default layout, but default layout is not good looking. i want change it , so i did the method .

Answer (score 0):

`ListActivity` does not need to call `setContentView(layoutResId)`.

If there is no call `setConentView()` in `ListActivity`, then the default layout has one `ListView` that fills out the Layout. It has its own `ListView`, whose ID is `android.R.id.list`.

If you want to create a new Layout that is displayed in `ListActivity`, not just `Activity`, then you have to set the ID of the `ListView` in XML as `@android:id/list`.

Custom IDs such as `@+id/newListView` won't work in `ListActivity`'s own methods like `getListAdapter()`, `setListAdapter()`, etc. If you want to use these functions, you have to set the ID of the `ListView` as `@android:id/list`.

For more information, see the official Android developer [site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: default layout is not good looking. i want change as my own layout,so i used the function, i have tryed change listActivity as Activity and define a listview and set as u said ,but the result is same,still have that problem.